# Passing Lists to Controller Asp.Net MVC Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, list

I have problem passing list data from JS to Controller, as the list is stringify the ajax is not submitted to Controller. What changes should i make to javascript and controller method to do it. Any help, links to acheive it.

**Javascript**

```
 $('#submit').click(function () {
    var isAllValid = true;
    var list = [];

        var orderItem = {

            Agency: $('.AgentName', this).val(),
            SectorPair: $('select.sectorCategory', this).val().trim(),
            ForPAX: $('.foreignPax', this).val(),
            IndPAX: $('.indianPax', this).val(),
            FlightDate: $('.flightDate', this).val(),
            Airlines: $('select.airlineCategory', this).val().trim()
        }
        list.push(orderItem);
        //}
    })

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/DomesticDeparture/Create',
            data: JSON.stringify(list),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status) {
                    alert('Successfully saved');
                    //here we will clear the form
                    list = [];
                    $('#airlineName,#departureDate').val('');
                    $('#orderdetailsItems').empty();
                    $('#AgentName').focus();
                }
                else {
                    alert('Error');
                }
                $('#submit').text('Save');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                $('#submit').text('Save');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

and **Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create( List<DomesticDepartureEntry> dentries)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       foreach (var a in dentries)
            {
                db.DomesticDepartureEntries.AddRange(dentries);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Your method has the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute and your not passing a token, so your method would never even execute.

Comment: And then your method returns View which makes no sense based on the code in your success callback

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ajax don't fire and reach to controller but data is binded in the list.

Comment: It also has `return RedirectToAction("Index");` which makes no sense either - ajax calls never redirect

Comment: @StephenMuecke those could just be leftover annotations after being converted from a form-post to a javascript ajax

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson, Not sure what you mean by that or what difference it makes. The method will never be executed because of the `AntiForgeryToken` is not passed in the ajax call (OP is getting a `500 (Internal Server Error)` (but there are so many other errors in the code anyway)

Comment: @StephenMuecke It works after removing AntiForgeryToken but data are inserted twice i.e 4 rows are inserted for 2 rows of data. Though data is inserted it throws Error message as alert.

Comment: What do your mean 4 rows - you only pass a collection containing one object in your ajax call so I assumes you have not shown the real code. And the fact its `$('#submit').click(...` also suggests its a submit button so your making a normal submit and an ajax call (because you do not cancel the default submit) which would explain saving twice.

Comment: But why are you making an ajax call anyway (none of your code is making much sense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Without ajax how can i throw list to controller.

Comment: If you have generated your view correctly, then it would be correctly bound (I have no idea what your view looks like, but you might start with [this answer](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164301/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-patricia) to understand how to bind to collections)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you please suggest how to remove ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Make an API controller like the following:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/CreateRecord")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateRecord([FromBody] List<DomesticDepartureEntry> dentries)
        {
            try
            {
               if (ModelState.IsValid)
               {
                  db.DomesticDepartureEntries.AddRange(dentries);
                  db.SaveChanges();
                  return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new ObjectContent<JObject>(new JObject { new JProperty("message", "Record successfully inserted into the database!") }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()),
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
                };

               }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               return new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new ObjectContent<JObject>(new JObject { new JProperty("message", $"Failed because: {ex.Message}") }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()),
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed
                };
            }
        }
}
```

You don't return a view to the AJAX success callback, you return a JSON object to the callback alongwith the status code.

And modify your AJAX call to route it to the following Web API:

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/CreateRecord',
        data: JSON.stringify(list),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data)
        {
              if(!$.isEmptyObject(data)){
                console.log( data["message"] );
                alert( data["message"]);

                //Your business logic
                //here we will clear the form
                list = [];
                $('#airlineName,#departureDate').val('');
                $('#orderdetailsItems').empty();
                $('#AgentName').focus();
             }
            else
                 alert('Some error occured!');
        },
        error: function ( jqXHR, errorThrown, statusText )
        {
                console.log( errorThrown );
                alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: OP has tagged this `asp.net-mvc` NOT `asp.net-web-api`!